# Windowes share dosn't mount at startup

Tags: mount, fstab, automount

I'm trying to get a windows share to mount at startup. I have followed [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) description. It works fine to run a `sudo mount -a`
But at restart / boot nothing happens.

My `fstab` looks like this

```
//erik-bkup/delad  /media/test  cifs username=myname,password=mypassword,domain=mydomain,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp  0  0
```

In my `journalctl - log` I have the following error message

```
systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
systemd[1]: Failed to mount /media/test.
```

Found that using this command I received the log file for `rc.local`

```
sudo systemctl status rc-local
```

And it gives me the following error log

```
    rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mån 2017-06-26 18:01:11 CEST; 2h 10min ago
  Process: 961 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jun 26 18:01:11 kontor systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
jun 26 18:01:11 kontor rc.local[961]: mount error: could not resolve address for erik-bkup: Unknown error
jun 26 18:01:11 kontor systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
jun 26 18:01:11 kontor systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
jun 26 18:01:11 kontor systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Unit entered failed state.
jun 26 18:01:11 kontor systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
~
```

Wondering if I'm on the right path here, if `rc.local` might be the problem why my shared folder is not automounts

Comment: The description you followed is somewhat outdated. Did you add the `mount` command to your `/etc/rc.local`? The error message says `could not resolve address for erik-bkup`- probably at the time of mounting the DNS is not working. If `erik-bkup` has a fixed IP address, add that to your `/etc/hosts` file, so the address can be resolved.

Comment: What is the output of `nmblookup erik-bkup`?

Comment: Thank you for your posts!

@ridgy You wrote that the description was a bit outdated, is there any other description I should follow to be able to mount a windows share on startup?

In my /etc/rc.local I have added the following line
**mount /media/test**

Erik-bkup does not have a fixed ip address, despite that, I tried to add the line

**192.168.1.72  erik-bkup** 
 Without desirable results

The output for nmblookup erik-bkup is
**192.168.1.72 erik-bkup<00>**